# Base64 Conversion issue between Python and JAVA

Tags: python, java, utf-8, base64

Good Morning

I'm having an issue converting a Base64 string back to a byte stream when using a compressed file. There appears to be a difference in the byte arrays between a pre converted string from python vs a byte conversion in Java.

**UPDATED:**

Apologies, I think my explanation left something to desire. I've attempted to simplify the issue into two scenarios.

**Scenario 1: Java Only (Successful scenario)**

A compressed file encoded as base64 is received into my Java application from a message queue...

H4sIAAAAAAAA/3WSzW7sIAyF9zyFd7PJS0xX7aaq1JG6ZsAJdAiOwBlu3v4eyGwrRVGCfzjfsW+B"C9O6V6U7U5WV6RGzJ5mp2YNkV7XUc8y3jZ40MP3KgwupjB8NkWdz6xmXikNBLxfISZ73GiWbD3I2"X5QWVspChVMvMG+IZq6VVs5T73SQLzE/aD2oIWK+kjTEyMeln7EtGsynZEY4JUr85ESSh4jUCz7l"Lh6K5xlaPIVYqUnx5p2PCQSHQQaut7UXydDD/1xU9l3+CdITB386qG7gPMnIdo9sPuj8WyUvtFfz"E4Rmhg4NVqFiZsKt913JDpdAqRPtYRpnh+xkYe3HRI0vT4bh3PUX2ZcwWphr7hajB54sCvsLzVZh"voBYcSdVlY3UJqi8IJYqQ2uWNiACCjAGsGmExITSF/t7f11hnE1dfHetWXVBpXExX7DecaUHbzpi"z8gNeDGBNqUzXfo4nMWGdIrGWc0bjJkFQiuXp81ap74C5odTOrmxPzV62HIOyknymGhVi+vMtY/S"O1jnsVpLkZbMrWFIqCiY3vB624pYF4DzcqcvAD7uvNgxyICyF+SffH9G/gMaqXG6/wIAAA==

It is passed through the following code...

```
byte[] decodedPayload = inlineAttachment.getPayload().getBytes("UTF-8");
decodedPayload = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(inlineAttachment.getPayload());

if (inlineAttachment.isCompressed()) {
    GZIPInputStream inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedPayload));
    payload = inputStream.readAllBytes();
}
```

There are no issues with this the file is decompressed.
It should be noted that the decodedPayload before the decompression looks like this as a string…

��������u��n� ��<�w��KLW�ԑ�f�    t��n���l+EQ�8߱o�ӺW�;S����'��كdW��s̷��40�ʃ��
�gs���CA/�I��%�r6_�V�B�S/0o�f��V�S�t�/1?h=�!b��4��ǥ��-̧dF8%J��D����>�.��Z<�X�I�杏   �A�������\T�]�   �:�n�<��v�l>��[%/�W��f�
V�bf­�]��@��ag��da��D�/O����ٗ0Z�k���,
��Va��Xq'U���&�� �*Ck�6
0�i�Ą��{]a�M]|w�YuA�q1_��q�o:b��
x1�6�3]�8�ņt��Y���B+���Z���S:��?5z�r�I�hU��̵��;X�ZK��̭aH�(���zۊX��r�/�>��1Ȁ��|F��q����

and this as a byte string...

[31, -117, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 117, -110, -51, 110, -20, 32, 12, -123, -9, 60, -123, 119, -77, -55, 75, 76, 87, -19, -90, -86, -44, -111, -70, 102, -64, 9, 116, 8, -114, -64,…

**Scenario 2: Python Base64 decode before Java decompression**

This time around we start off in the Python application, the Python application receives the base64 string and decodes it via the following...

```
bpayload = payload.encode('utf-8')
splitLines = bpayload.splitlines()
splitlinesb = b''.join(splitLines)
value, defects = decode_b(splitlinesb)
```

In python the base64 byte array is as follows...

b"\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xffu\x92\xcdn\xec \x0c\x85\xf7<\x85w\xb3\xc9KLW\xed\xa6\xaa\xd4\x91\xbaf\xc0\tt\x08\x8e\xc0\x19n\xde\xfe\x1e\xc8l+EQ\x82\x7f8\xdf\xb1o\x81\x0b\xd3\xbaW\xa5;S\x95\x95\xe9\x11\xb3'\x99\xa9\xd9\x83dW\xb5\xd4s\xcc\xb7\x8d\x9e40\xfd\xca\x83\x0b\xa9\x8c\x1f\r\x91gs\xeb\x19\x97\x8aCA/\x17\xc8I\x9e\xf7\x1a%\x9b\x0fr6_\x94\x16V\xcaB\x85S/0o\x88f\xae\x95V\xceS\xeft\x90/1?h=\xa8!b\xbe\x924\xc4\xc8\xc7\xa5\x9f\xb1-\x1a\xcc\xa7dF8%J\xfc\xe4D\x92\x87\x88\xd4\x0b>\xe5.\x1e\x8a\xe7\x19Z<\x85X\xa9I\xf1\xe6\x9d\x8f\t\x04\x87A\x06\xae\xb7\xb5\x17\xc9\xd0\xc3\xff\T\xf6]\xfe\t\xd2\x13\x07\x7f:\xa8n\xe0<\xc9\xc8v\x8fl>\xe8\xfc[%/\xb4W\xf3\x13\x84f\x86\x0e\rV\xa1bf\xc2\xad\xf7]\xc9\x0e\x97@\xa9\x13\xeda\x1ag\x87\xecda\xed\xc7D\x8d/O\x86\xe1\xdc\xf5\x17\xd9\x970Z\x98k\xee\x16\xa3\x07\x9e,\n\xfb\x0b\xcdVa\xbe\x80Xq'U\x95\x8d\xd4&\xa8\xbc \x96*Ck\x966 \x02\n0\x06\xb0i\x84\xc4\x84\xd2\x17\xfb{\x7f]a\x9cM]|w\xadYuA\xa5q1_\xb0\xdeq\xa5\x07o:b\xcf\xc8\rx1\x816\xa53]\xfa8\x9c\xc5\x86t\x8a\xc6Y\xcd\x1b\x8c\x99\x05B+\x97\xa7\xcdZ\xa7\xbe\x02\xe6\x87S:\xb9\xb1?5z\xd8r\x0e\xcaI\xf2\x98hU\x8b\xeb\xcc\xb5\x8f\xd2;X\xe7\xb1ZK\x91\x96\xcc\xadaH\xa8(\x98\xde\xf0z\xdb\x8aX\x17\x80\xf3r\xa7/\x00>\xee\xbc\xd81\xc8\x80\xb2\x17\xe4\x9f|\x7fF\xfe\x03\x1a\xa9q\xba\xff\x02\x00\x00”

This is then placed into a message queue, the data looks like (covering all views of the data)...

\u001f\ufffd\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\ufffdu\ufffd\ufffdn\ufffd \f\ufffd\ufffd<\ufffdw\ufffd\ufffdKLW\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u0511\ufffdf\ufffd\tt\b\ufffd\ufffd\u0019n\ufffd\ufffd\u001e\ufffdl+EQ\ufffd\u007f8\u07f1o\ufffd\u000b\u04faW\ufffd;S\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u0011\ufffd'\ufffd\ufffd\u0643dW\ufffd\ufffds\u0337\ufffd\ufffd40\ufffd\u0283\u000b\ufffd\ufffd\u001f\r\ufffdgs\ufffd\u0019\ufffd\ufffdCA/\u0017\ufffdI\ufffd\ufffd\u001a%\ufffd\u000fr6_\ufffd\u0016V\ufffdB\ufffdS/0o\ufffdf\ufffd\ufffdV\ufffdS\ufffdt\ufffd/1?h=\ufffd!b\ufffd\ufffd4\ufffd\ufffd\u01e5\ufffd\ufffd-\u001a\u0327dF8%J\ufffd\ufffdD\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u000b>\ufffd.\u001e\ufffd\ufffd\u0019Z<\ufffdX\ufffdI\ufffd\u674f\t\u0004\ufffdA\u0006\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u0017\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\T\ufffd]\ufffd\t\ufffd\u0013\u0007\u007f:\ufffdn\ufffd<\ufffd\ufffdv\ufffdl>\ufffd\ufffd[%/\ufffdW\ufffd\u0013\ufffdf\ufffd\u000e\rV\ufffdbf\u00ad\ufffd]\ufffd\u000e\ufffd@\ufffd\u0013\ufffda\u001ag\ufffd\ufffdda\ufffd\ufffdD\ufffd/O\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u0017\u06570Z\ufffdk\ufffd\u0016\ufffd\u0007\ufffd,\n\ufffd\u000b\ufffdVa\ufffd\ufffdXq'U\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd&\ufffd\ufffd \ufffd*Ck\ufffd6 \u0002\n0\u0006\ufffdi\ufffd\u0104\ufffd\u0017\ufffd{\u007f]a\ufffdM]|w\ufffdYuA\ufffdq1_\ufffd\ufffdq\ufffd\u0007o:b\ufffd\ufffd\rx1\ufffd6\ufffd3]\ufffd8\ufffd\u0146t\ufffd\ufffdY\ufffd\u001b\ufffd\ufffd\u0005B+\ufffd\ufffd\ufffdZ\ufffd\ufffd\u0002\ufffdS:\ufffd\ufffd?5z\ufffdr\u000e\ufffdI\ufffdhU\ufffd\ufffd\u0335\ufffd\ufffd;X\ufffdZK\ufffd\ufffd\u032daH\ufffd(\ufffd\ufffd\ufffdz\u06caX\u0017\ufffd\ufffdr\ufffd/\u0000>\ufffd\ufffd1\u0200\ufffd\u0017\ufffd|\u007fF\ufffd\u0003\u001a\ufffdq\ufffd\ufffd\u0002\u0000\u0000

We now get to the **Java side**, the message is pulled off the queue and we attempt to decompress the given message only as the Base64 decode has already occurred...

```
byte[] decodedPayload = inlineAttachment.getPayload().getBytes("UTF-8");

if (inlineAttachment.isCompressed()) {
    GZIPInputStream inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedPayload));
    payload = inputStream.readAllBytes();
}
```

The decoded payload looks like this as a string...

��������u��n� ��<�w��KLW���ԑ�f�  t��n���l+EQ�8߱o�ӺW�;S����'��كdW��s̷��40�ʃ��
�gs���CA/�I��%�r6_�V�B�S/0o�f��V�S�t�/1?h=�!b��4��ǥ��-̧dF8%J��D����>�.��Z<�X�I�杏   �A�������\T�]�   �:�n�<��v�l>��[%/�W��f�
V�bf­�]��@��ag��da��D�/O����ٗ0Z�k���,
��Va��Xq'U���&�� �*Ck�6
0�i�Ą��{]a�M]|w�YuA�q1_��q�o:b��
x1�6�3]�8�ņt��Y���B+���Z���S:��?5z�r�I�hU��̵��;X�ZK��̭aH�(���zۊX��r�/�>��1Ȁ��|F��q����

and this is the byte array...

[31, -17, -65, -67, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -17, -65, -67, 117, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, 110, -17, -65, -67, 32, 12, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, 60, -17, -65, -67, 119...

There is a difference at this point between the Java version which is KLW���ԑ�f� vs KLW�ԑ�f� in the first line.

It is this scenario which will not decompress, although the string versions of the file are almost identical, the byte arrays are significantly different.

Many Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you encoded Python string in UTF-8? You didn't insert Python code, so it is difficult to check.

Comment: `-17, -65, -67` is the Unicode *character* for "I can't decode this into a character" (\uFFFD) �

Comment: base64 consists of ASCII characters only.  If you call getBytes("UTF-8") on a base64-encoded string, all byte values should be positive.  The fact that you got some negative values means your payload is not a base64-encoded string.

Comment: Actually, looking more carefully at the sequence of steps described, they don't make sense. *byte[] decodedPayload = inlineAttachment.getPayload().getBytes("UTF-8");* THEN *This goes on into my code and is successfully decompressed by...GZIPInputStream inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedPayload));* The first code line would only make sense if the attachment were purely UTF-8 text. BUT, the bit about then treating that as zipped data makes no sense at all. Then you say: *if (!inlineAttachment.isBase64())* (*not* Base64) but then proceed to decode it as Base64!

Comment: *The base64 string...* No, that's not base64. It contains several double quote marks

Comment: @g00se Oddly, Python's `b64decode` method works even with the quotes in the string.  Reversing the final result back to a b64 string does not generate the string with the quotes, but is otherwise the same.  I experimented and injected other non-base64 characters and it still decoded.  The algorithm must ignore non-base64 characters.

Comment: Yes, it copes with it somehow. The string falls over with GNU base64

Comment: I've updated the original question with a breakdown of the two scenarios more. 

There does seem to be a \uFFFD reference after the python base64 decode, it seems odd that the string versions match though.

Comment: Why are you encoding with UTF-8 before decoding?  That's not correct.  If you need to convert from `str` to `bytes` use `.encode('latin1')`.  Look at my answer for the sequence to decode, and `.b64decode` can start with a `bytes` or `str` object.

Comment: "Then it gets placed in the message queue" and becomes a mess of `\ufffd`.  Show a [mcve] on *how* it is placed in the message queue.  It looks like some kind of `.decode('utf8',errors='replace')` is going on to get the U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER code points.  That's corrupting the data.  You want the *raw* bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show Python code so I don't know where you went wrong, but you definitely shouldn't get negative numbers.  I suspect the decoding steps are applied in the wrong order.

This decodes your BASE64 string:

```py
import base64
import gzip

s = b'H4sIAAAAAAAA/3WSzW7sIAyF9zyFd7PJS0xX7aaq1JG6ZsAJdAiOwBlu3v4eyGwrRVGCfzjfsW+B"C9O6V6U7U5WV6RGzJ5mp2YNkV7XUc8y3jZ40MP3KgwupjB8NkWdz6xmXikNBLxfISZ73GiWbD3I2"X5QWVspChVMvMG+IZq6VVs5T73SQLzE/aD2oIWK+kjTEyMeln7EtGsynZEY4JUr85ESSh4jUCz7l"Lh6K5xlaPIVYqUnx5p2PCQSHQQaut7UXydDD/1xU9l3+CdITB386qG7gPMnIdo9sPuj8WyUvtFfz"E4Rmhg4NVqFiZsKt913JDpdAqRPtYRpnh+xkYe3HRI0vT4bh3PUX2ZcwWphr7hajB54sCvsLzVZh"voBYcSdVlY3UJqi8IJYqQ2uWNiACCjAGsGmExITSF/t7f11hnE1dfHetWXVBpXExX7DecaUHbzpi"z8gNeDGBNqUzXfo4nMWGdIrGWc0bjJkFQiuXp81ap74C5odTOrmxPzV62HIOyknymGhVi+vMtY/S"O1jnsVpLkZbMrWFIqCiY3vB624pYF4DzcqcvAD7uvNgxyICyF+SffH9G/gMaqXG6/wIAAA=='

step1 = base64.b64decode(s)
step2 = gzip.decompress(step1)
step3 = step2.decode('utf8')
print(step3)
```

Output:

```
There must be some kind of way outta here
Said the joker to the thief
There's too much confusion
I can't get no relief

Business men, they drink my wine
Plowmen dig my earth
None will level on the line
Nobody offered his word
Hey, hey

No reason to get excited
The thief, he kindly spoke
There are many here among us
Who feel that life is but a joke
But, uh, but you and I, we've been through that
And this is not our fate
So let us stop talkin' falsely now
The hour's getting late, hey

Hey

All along the watchtower
Princes kept the view
While all the women came and went
Barefoot servants, too
Well, uh, outside in the cold distance
A wildcat did growl
Two riders were approaching
And the wind began to howl, hey

All along the watchtower

All along the watchtower
```

Comment: It's good to know it decompress on the python side, however, the decompression only ever happens on the python side. Only the Base64 Decode occurs on the Python side. I've updated my original question to try and make the workflow clearer. 

This would suggest that a slight redesign of the process should work.

Answer (score 0):

Java too requires no quotation marks in Base64. The commented line below will cause the code to fail:

```
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;

public class Zimmerman {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = """
                H4sIAAAAAAAA/3WSzW7sIAyF9zyFd7PJS0xX7aaq1JG6ZsAJdAiOwBlu3v4eyGwrRVGCfzjfsW+B\"C9O6V6U7U5WV6RGzJ5mp2YNkV7XUc8y3jZ40MP3KgwupjB8NkWdz6xmXikNBLxfISZ73GiWbD3I2\"X5QWVspChVMvMG+IZq6VVs5T73SQLzE/aD2oIWK+kjTEyMeln7EtGsynZEY4JUr85ESSh4jUCz7l\"Lh6K5xlaPIVYqUnx5p2PCQSHQQaut7UXydDD/1xU9l3+CdITB386qG7gPMnIdo9sPuj8WyUvtFfz\"E4Rmhg4NVqFiZsKt913JDpdAqRPtYRpnh+xkYe3HRI0vT4bh3PUX2ZcwWphr7hajB54sCvsLzVZh\"voBYcSdVlY3UJqi8IJYqQ2uWNiACCjAGsGmExITSF/t7f11hnE1dfHetWXVBpXExX7DecaUHbzpi\"z8gNeDGBNqUzXfo4nMWGdIrGWc0bjJkFQiuXp81ap74C5odTOrmxPzV62HIOyknymGhVi+vMtY/S\"O1jnsVpLkZbMrWFIqCiY3vB624pYF4DzcqcvAD7uvNgxyICyF+SffH9G/gMaqXG6/wIAAA==""";
        //s = s.replaceAll("\"", "");
        try (Reader in = new InputStreamReader(
                new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(s.getBytes("UTF-8")))),
                "UTF-8")) {
            int buf = -1;
            while ((buf = in.read()) > -1) {
                System.out.print((char) buf);
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: There is a difference between Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode and Base64.getDecoder().

The MimeDecoder supports a different standard that can be in the form of...
"Each line of the output is no longer than 76 characters. Also, it ends with a carriage return followed by a linefeed (\r\n):"

Comment: Yes. I haven't tried whether the mime decoder will fail with double quotes in the encoding, but if I were forced to place a bet, I'd say it would